# Combine output from two commands into single table with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to display the output of the following commands which are as below-:

1)

```
mount | grep -i "/dev/sd*" | awk '{ print NR "\t" $1 "\t" $3 }'
```

2)

```
/usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep Device: | awk '{print $2 }'
```

The 1st comand displays 3 columns with multiple rows and the next command displays one one column of information.

I want to concat the outputs of both the commands and concat and display as 4 columns with multiple rows. Please suggest.

Comment: provide sample data outputs of 1 and 2

Comment: `/dev/sd*` will match all lines containing `/dev/s` followed by any number of `d`s, including zero. (Every occurrence of `dev/s` is followed by any number of `d`s.)

Answer (score 6):

This is what `paste` is for. Use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to make the shell treat your commands like files:

```
paste <(mount | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /\/dev\/sd*/ {print NR "\t" $1 "\t" $3}') \
      <(/usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sdb | awk '/Device:/ {print $2}')
```

I removed the grep commands, which awk can easily do.

Answer (score 3):

Make a named pipe to hold the first command's output:

```
mkfifo mount_output
mount | grep -i "/dev/sd.*" | awk '{ print NR "\t" $1 "\t" $3 }' > mount_output &
```

Then use `paste`:

```
/usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep Device: | awk '{print $2 }' | paste foo -
```

Note that `awk '{print $2 }'` can be simplified to `cut -d' ' -f2`. Making a temporary named pipe is more properly done with

```
tempd=`mktemp -d`
mkfifo ${tempd}/mount_output
```

then `rm -rf "$tempd"` when the pipe is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

If you've already got awk in your command line, you don't really need grep.  So you can do this:

```
mount | awk '/\/dev\/sd/ {print NR, $1, $3}'
smartctl -a /dev/sdb | awk '/Device:/ {print $2}'
```

If you want to produce one line of output for each device, you can pipe the output of your first command line into a loop, and then run smartctl inside the loop, like this:

```
mount | awk '/\/dev\/sd/ {print NR, $1, $3}' | while read nr dev mntpt; do
  echo -e "$nr\t$dev\t$mntpt\t$(smartctl -a $dev | awk '/Device:/ {print $2}')"
done
```

The `-e` flag to echo is necessary to make it recognize `\t` as a tab character.